# Intensity normalization of image using Python+PIL - Speed issues

Tags: python, normalization, python-imaging-library

I'm working on a little problem in my sparetime involving analysis of some images obtained through a microscope. It is a wafer with some stuff here and there, and ultimately I want to make a program to detect when certain materials show up.

Anyways, first step is to normalize the intensity across the image, since the lens does not give uniform lightning. Currently I use an image, with no stuff on, only the substrate, as a background, or reference, image. I find the maximum of the three (intensity) values for RGB.

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw

rmax = 0;gmax = 0;bmax = 0;rmin = 300;gmin = 300;bmin = 300

im_old = Image.open("test_image.png")
im_back = Image.open("background.png")

maxx = im_old.size[0] #Import the size of the image
maxy = im_old.size[1]
im_new = Image.new("RGB", (maxx,maxy))


pixback = im_back.load()
for x in range(maxx):
    for y in range(maxy):
        if pixback[x,y][0] > rmax:
            rmax = pixback[x,y][0]
        if pixback[x,y][1] > gmax:
            gmax = pixback[x,y][1]
        if pixback[x,y][2] > bmax:
            bmax = pixback[x,y][2]


pixnew = im_new.load()
pixold = im_old.load()
for x in range(maxx):
    for y in range(maxy):
        r = float(pixold[x,y][0]) / ( float(pixback[x,y][0])*rmax )
        g = float(pixold[x,y][1]) / ( float(pixback[x,y][1])*gmax )
        b = float(pixold[x,y][2]) / ( float(pixback[x,y][2])*bmax )
        pixnew[x,y] = (r,g,b)
```

The first part of the code determines the maximum intensity of the RED, GREEN and BLUE channels, pixel by pixel, of the background image, but needs only be done once.

The second part takes the "real" image (with stuff on it), and normalizes the RED, GREEN and BLUE channels, pixel by pixel, according to the background. This takes some time, 5-10 seconds for an 1280x960 image, which is way too slow if I need to do this to several images.

**What can I do to improve the speed?** I thought of moving all the images to numpy arrays, but I can't seem to find a fast way to do that for RGB images.
I'd rather not move away from python, since my C++ is quite low-level, and getting a working FORTRAN code would probably take longer than I could ever save in terms of speed :P

Comment: This probably belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ more than here.

Comment: @S.Lott, I think it's a gray area. The question is regarding a specific technology after all.

Comment: @Mark Ransom: How does "specific technology" make it gray?  It's code.  To be reviewed.

Comment: @S.Lott, perhaps you're right, it's not gray after all. I just re-read the FAQ and I can't see a single problem with this question.

Comment: @Bjarke: have you thought about OpenCV?  It's a powerful image processing library with Python bindings.  It is quick with reading and writing, and has, for example, an adaptiveThreshold algorithm.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

def normalize(arr):
    """
    Linear normalization
    http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalization_%28image_processing%29
    """
    arr = arr.astype('float')
    # Do not touch the alpha channel
    for i in range(3):
        minval = arr[...,i].min()
        maxval = arr[...,i].max()
        if minval != maxval:
            arr[...,i] -= minval
            arr[...,i] *= (255.0/(maxval-minval))
    return arr

def demo_normalize():
    img = Image.open(FILENAME).convert('RGBA')
    arr = np.array(img)
    new_img = Image.fromarray(normalize(arr).astype('uint8'),'RGBA')
    new_img.save('/tmp/normalized.png')
```

Comment: when i do this on greyscale image (changed convert and save to 'L') i cant tell any difference compared to just converting to greyscale (except that it 
is about 3 times larger filesize). with color its also larger but i can visually tell difference. where does the filesize increase come from? should i be able to notice a diff in greyscale normalisation, and if so, what else do i need to change here if anything? i noticed the wiki gives the example of the same formula for greyscale.

Comment: If you have a greyscale image, then `arr` will have shape `(H, W)` instead of `(H, W, 4)`. Therefore, you don't need to normalize each channel, `arr[..., i]`. Instead you'd normalize `arr` itself. So remove the `for-loop` and change `arr[..., i]` to `arr`.

Answer (score 2):

See http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.misc.fromimage.html#scipy.misc.fromimage

You can say

```
databack = scipy.misc.fromimage(pixback)
rmax = numpy.max(databack[:,:,0])
gmax = numpy.max(databack[:,:,1])
bmax = numpy.max(databack[:,:,2])
```

which should be much faster  than looping over all (r,g,b) triplets of your image.
Then you can do

```
dataold = scip.misc.fromimage(pixold)
r = dataold[:,:,0] / (pixback[:,:,0] * rmax )
g = dataold[:,:,1] / (pixback[:,:,1] * gmax )
b = dataold[:,:,2] / (pixback[:,:,2] * bmax )

datanew = numpy.array((r,g,b))
imnew = scipy.misc.toimage(datanew)
```

The code is not tested, but should work somehow with minor modifications.

Comment: While this is indeed quite(!) fast compared to my (w)hack, something seems to be off with the scipy function. E.g. using an image like http://farm1.static.flickr.com/58/165782919_38f15d585a.jpg the following code should show the red channel of the image, but that does not seem to be the case:

`scipy.misc.toimage(databack[:,:,0]).show()`

Comment: Unutbu gave another solution which does not use scipy to convert images and numpy data in both directions. Maybe you should try something like 
    arr=np.array(np.asarray(img).astype('float'))
    new_img = Image.fromarray(normalize(arr).astype('uint8'),'RGBA')

Answer (score 1):

This is partially from [FolksTalk webpage](https://www.folkstalk.com/tech/pil-normalize-image-with-code-examples/):

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

# Read image file
in_file = "my_image.png"
# convert('RGB') for PNG file type
image = Image.open(in_file).convert('RGB')
pixels = np.asarray(image)

# Convert from integers to floats
pixels = pixels.astype('float32')

# Normalize to the range 0-1
pixels /= 255.0
```