# Python: display a matrix with negative and positive values

Tags: python, image, matlab

I have a matrix `m` with positive and negative values. I would like to visualize this matrix in Python.  In MATLAB, I can display this matrix so that the most negative value gets mapped to 0 while the most positive value gets mapped to 255 through using `imshow(m, []);`. How can I do this equivalently under python?

Comment: Normalize your image so that it spans between `[0,255]` referring to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7422204/intensity-normalization-of-image-using-pythonpil-speed-issues.  After, use the `show()` method from PIL. http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm#tag-Image.Image.show

Comment: There is no simpler method?

Comment: Yes.  Look at Amro's post.

Comment: @rayryeng: actually the `imshow(img,[])` syntax in MATLAB is equivalent to: [`imshow(img, 'DisplayRange',[min(img(:)) max(img(:))])`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imshow.html#inputarg_DisplayRange) (which in the end affects the [`CLim` property](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes_props.html#zmw57dd0e33234) of the axes). So it's not actually scaling the image at all...

Comment: @Amro - Yes I'm aware it isn't scaling the image at all.  Poor choice of words.  I'll modify the post.  Thanks!

Comment: @Amro What does "it's not actually scaling the image at all" mean? :)

Comment: @Jingtao: **scaling** the image implies converting the values from some range to an another (say from [-5,3] to [0,1]) before displaying it. What's really happening with the above is rather **color mapping**; so for a grayscale colormap, the minimum value is mapped to black and the max value mapped to white. Values in between are mapped to intermediate shades of gray, using a number of gray levels equal to the colormap length. The difference is subtle and in the end the result is practically the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like it gets scaled by default using matplotlib's `imshow`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.array([[1.0,2.0], [-3.0,-2.0]], dtype='float')

plt.imshow(x, interpolation='none')
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[image: matrix]

Comment: +1 - Nice.  I totally forgot `matplotlib` has `imshow`.  Sweet!

Comment: How to show it in grayscale? :)

Comment: set the colormap as such: `plt.imshow(.., cmap='gray')`. Here is a quick tutorial to get you started: http://matplotlib.org/users/image_tutorial.html

Answer (score 2):

`imshow` accepts color scale minimum and maximum:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create some data with both negative and positive values
data = np.random.randn(10,10)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
im = ax.imshow(data, vmin=-.2, vmax=.2, interpolation='nearest', cmap=plt.cm.gray, aspect='auto')
fig.colorbar(im)
```

(Just note that I use the object-oriented notation. If you use the stateful inteface, then naturally it is only `imshow(...)`, etc. The main point is in the keyword arguments.)

Of the keyword arguments `vmin` and `vmax` tell the color map scaling, `cmap` defines the color map, and `aspect='auto'` makes the image scalable in both dimensions. The `interpolation` argument is nice to test yourself (just leave it out and see what happens).

In this case the lowest color (values <= -.2) is black and the highest color (values >= .2) is white:

[image]