# Why tesseract gives different results on almost same pictures?

Tags: tesseract

Screenshots have been captured on two windows 10 machines with the same tesseract (I just copied tesseract folder from one to another machine). I noticed that every 2 corresponding pixels in images differ in 1-2 (I have no idea why they are different. Both have been made using python pillow's `ImageGrab` module. Windows color settings are identical). I tried to normalize images (https://stackoverflow.com/a/7422584/13635865), but with other images it doesn't work. Tesseract version:

```
tesseract v5.1.0.20220510
 leptonica-1.78.0
  libgif 5.1.4 : libjpeg 8d (libjpeg-turbo 1.5.3) : libpng 1.6.34 : libtiff 4.0.9 : zlib 1.2.11 : libwebp 0.6.1 : libopenjp2 2.3.0
 Found AVX2
 Found AVX
 Found FMA
 Found SSE4.1
 Found libarchive 3.5.0 zlib/1.2.11 liblzma/5.2.3 bz2lib/1.0.6 liblz4/1.7.5 libzstd/1.4.5
 Found libcurl/7.77.0-DEV Schannel zlib/1.2.11 zstd/1.4.5 libidn2/2.0.4 nghttp2/1.31.0
```

cmd: `tesseract <good/bad>.png stdout -l rus`
Result with `good.png`: `Карта получателя`
Result with `bad.png`: `ЕВЕ`
Good image: https://ibb.co/bHLtP67
Bad image: https://ibb.co/G3FT2cT
Why there is such a big difference in tesseract results on almost the same images?

Answer (score 1):

Can not reproduce problem:

```
>tesseract good.png - -l rus
Карта получателя

>tesseract bad.png - -l rus
Карта получателя

>tesseract -v
tesseract 5.1.0-70-g0df5
 leptonica-1.83.0 (Jun 24 2022, 17:48:50) [MSC v.1929 LIB Release x64]
  libgif 5.2.1 : libjpeg 6b (libjpeg-turbo 2.0.91) : libpng 1.6.37 : libtiff 4.4.0 : zlib 1.2.12 : libwebp 1.2.2 : libopenjp2 2.5.0
 Found AVX2
 Found AVX
 Found FMA
 Found SSE4.1
 Found libarchive 3.5.1 zlib/1.2.11 liblzma/5.2.4 bz2lib/1.0.6 libzstd/1.4.9
 Found libcurl/7.75.0 zlib/1.2.12 libssh2/1.10.1_DEV
```

Comment: I just updated tesseract from 5.1.0 to 5.2.0 and the problem dissappeared. Magic :)